# Trigger to delete prior duplicate records in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to write a trigger based on the following condition

Before inserting a record in the table, I need to compare the value of one column to the existing records, and if records found then I need to delete those records having same column value in the already existing records, and then need to insert that new record.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a job for a **stored procedure** that you call to insert your data - **not** a trigger ....

Comment: Marc,We are having some Webservices to insert the data into this table and we cant control this insertion of data , so want to create a trigger for this to delete records from the table before inserting a records if one column having same value in already existing records, We need to delete those existing records and then to insert new record.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CustomInsert_Trigger] ON [dbo].[Realtimebookingcount]
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Flag INT
    SELECT @Flag = Booking_NUM FROM inserted
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Realtimebookingcount
        WHERE Booking_NUM = @Flag) > 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Realtimebookingcount
        WHERE Realtimebookingcount.Booking_NUM = @Flag
    END
    INSERT INTO Realtimebookingcount 
    SELECT * FROM inserted
END`

Comment: Thank you so much Ram, I am having Booking_NUM column in the table Realtimebookingcount, we are inserting records via webservices and  need to ensure that there will be no prior records with the same booking_number.if yes then we need to delete those records from the table and then insert that new records.  We can't Create a new column on that Table. so Please Let me know your valuable suggestion for this Requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much Ram for Prompt help, Let me test this once in our server and then I will let you know the success